# СПП определительное?

Tags: спп, синтаксический-разбор

Телефонисты тут же мстительно вырубили важного начальника, который продолжал греметь в трубку отключенного телефона.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Совершенно верно. Союзное слово *который* в данном случае связывает две части сложного предложения.